# each row of table has input field and submit button, when ever i click button of that row the input field data is taken from first row only instead

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a code where i can update payment status with utr number and send mail , when i click submit button
everything is fine but the input data given from that particular row is not taken but only first row input field data is taken in every row

I have a code where i can update payment status with utr number and send mail with which, when i click submit button
everything is fine but the input data given from that particular row is not taken but only first row input field data is taken in every row

I have a code where i can update payment status with utr number and send mail with which, when i click submit button
everything is fine but the input data given from that particular row is not taken but only first row input field data is taken in every row

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nMUr.png)
This is my code

```
<?php
//index.php

require("conn.php");
$query = "SELECT entry.voucherno as id,entry.cheque_no,entry.net,bank_details.mail,bank_details.accountnumber,bank_details.name,entry.tds,entry.cgst1,entry.sgst1,entry.igst_tds,entry.cess,entry.deductions,entry.Description,entry.cheque_date,entry.sum,entry.entered,employees.mail as eemail FROM entry join bank_details on entry.name=bank_details.id join employees on entry.entered=employees.empname where entry.status='success' and bank_details.mail='thi@gmail.com'";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
   
 
?>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        
                        <th>account No</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Cheque No</th>
                        <th>Cheque Date</th>
                        <th>Mail</th>
                        <th>Sucess</th>
                        <th>Reverted</th>
                
                        
                    </tr>
                <?php
                $count = 0;
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["accountnumber"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["net"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cheque_no"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cheque_date"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["mail"].'</td>
                        
                        
                        
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="utr[]" id="task" class="inputdiv" value="" placeholder="UTR number" />
                        <input type="button" name="Success" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["mail"].'" data-name="'.$row["name"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'"
                            data-cheque_no="'.$row["cheque_no"].'"
                            data-cheque_date="'.$row["cheque_date"].'"
                            data-tds="'.$row["tds"].'"
                            data-cgst1="'.$row["cgst1"].'"
                            data-sgst1="'.$row["sgst1"].'"
                            data-igst_tds="'.$row["igst_tds"].'"
                            data-cess="'.$row["cess"].'"
                            data-description="'.$row["Description"].'"
                            data-accountnumber="'.$row["accountnumber"].'"
                            data-sum="'.$row["sum"].'"
                            data-eemail="'.$row["eemail"].'"
                            data-entered="'.$row["entered"].'"
                            data-id="'.$row["id"].'"
                            data-action="single" 
                            data-stat="success" value="Transaction Success">                    </td>
                        <td>
                        
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
                ?>
                    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.email_button').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var id  = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var email_data = [];
        if(action == 'single')
        {
            email_data.push({
                utr : $('#inputdiv').val(),
            
                email: $(this).data("email"),
                name: $(this).data("name"),
                        net: $(this).data("net"),
                id: $(this).data("id"),
                        cheque_no: $(this).data("cheque_no"),
                        cheque_date: $(this).data("cheque_date"),
                        tds: $(this).data("tds"),
                        cgst1: $(this).data("cgst1"),
                        sgst1: $(this).data("sgst1"),
                        igst_tds: $(this).data("igst_tds"),
                        cess: $(this).data("cess"),
                        description: $(this).data("description"),
                        sum: $(this).data("sum"),
                        accountnumber: $(this).data("accountnumber"),
                                       eemail: $(this).data("eemail"),
                        entered: $(this).data("entered")
            });
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:"send_mail.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{email_data:email_data},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#'+id).html('Sending...');
                $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger');
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'ok')
                {
                    $('#'+id).text('Success');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-info');
                    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-success');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#'+id).text(data);
                }
                $('#'+id).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })  

    });
}); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Trye changing `utr : $('#inputdiv').val(),` by `utr : $(this).prev('.inputdiv').val(),

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thank you so much brother it worked